# Please retag from [adl] to [argument-dependent-lookup]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Please retag questions from [adl](/questions/tagged/adl) to [argument-dependent-lookup](/questions/tagged/argument-dependent-lookup) and (possibly) make the former a tag-synonym of the latter. Making them synonyms is not without trouble, because there are two questions that use it with different meaning - one about "AIR Debug Launcher" and one about some "ATI ADL", versus 8 with the C++ ADL meaning. The tag [adl](/questions/tagged/adl) appears to be too ambiguous.

Comment: There are only 10 questions... and you certainly have the rep to edit...

Comment: @Jon I'm assuming mods have automated tools for that. So I won't try wasting my time going through them manually. I'm here for enjoying my time, not for doing repetitive tasks, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay done, but apparently I do not have enough power to edit the [Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/argument-dependent-lookup/info). Anyone?

Comment: I think I'd have preferred `[omg-adl-sux]`, but `[argument-dependent-lookup]` will do.  Thanks, Fred!

Comment: IIUC, @James and @Johannes should be able edit the wiki.

Comment: Yes, I can edit it; what do we want it to say?

Answer (score 2):

I'm all for it, let's do that.

For one, spelling out abbreviations make it easier to understand them, plus, as you said, there's the problem of the same abbreviation referring to different things.